# Python safe dict navigation, The Right Way

Tags: python, dictionary, idioms

## TLDR summary

I wrote a function `navigateDict` that does a safe navigation on a `dict`, similar to `dict.get()` but nested. It replaces code like

```
if 1 in data and 'i' in data[1] and 'a' in data[1]['i']:
    print data[1]['i']['a']
else:
    print "Not found"
```

with the roughly equivalent

```
found = navigateDict(data, 1, 'i', 'a')
if found is not None:
    print found
else:
    print "Not found"
```

- Is anything similar to this already part of the standard library?
- Is there a more idiomatic way to do the same thing?

  - Any response that requires typing any path component key more than once is probably a non-answer.

## Additional details

The implementation is as follows:

```
# Allow fallback value other than None
def navigateDictEx(d, keys, fallback=None):
    for key in keys:
        if key in d:
            d = d[key]
        else:
            return fallback
    return d

def navigateDict(d, *keys):
    return navigateDictEx(d, keys)
```

See the summary for example usage.

Pythonic or not, this function reduces repetition in a place where redundancy is a bad idea. For example, changing one path component in the example requires up to three distinct values to be modified as one in the original example, but only one in the modified example. Given my regular tendency to err, this is a big win.

Ultimately I'm asking this: Is there something in the standard library that does this, or am I going to need to find a place for it in my project's library?

## If hits are expected to dominate misses

brionius correctly points out that catching `KeyError` will work:

```
try:
    print data[1]['i']['a']
except KeyError:
    print "Not found"
```

This might be the way I go; it's pretty terse and cuts the repetition. However, it does reflect an assumption that there will be more hits than misses. If there's a better way of assuming the opposite I'd like to know that, also.

Comment: Just to complement, as of Python 3.11, you need catch the TypeError as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to do this is as follows:

```
try:
    print data[1]['i']['a']
except KeyError:
    print "Not found!"
```

It's in line with the spirit of duck-typing.  It may or may not be as fast, as I believe handling exceptions carries a certain amount of overhead, but it's certainly "safe".

Comment: Not a bad alternative. To keep the dialogue going, though, let's say I'm expecting more misses than hits.

Answer (score 5):

a solution like this is cool

https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/343823801278140417

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> infinite_defaultdict = lambda: defaultdict(infinite_defaultdict)
>>> d = infinite_defaultdict() 
>>> d['x']['y']['z'] = 10
>>> if d['x']['y']['z']: print d['x']['y']['z'] #better reflects that misses are common
```

Comment: Nice!  Was just trying to think of some way to make a "recursive" defaultdict.  The only downside is that just accessing an element of the dictionary fills it with an infinite_defaultdict object.

Comment: It also doesn't quite work with an existing `dict`. `d.update(data)` from an existing `dict` `data` doesn't make a deep copy, so a miss will still cause a `KeyError`. Coercing an empty value to `None` is also nontrivial to me, but that's more of a personal problem...

Comment: yeah it would have to replace the data dict not just update from it or you would have to figure out some scheme to manually populate it from an existing dict(probably not overly difficult but meh)

Comment: (To clarify, in general it won't be my code producing the dictionary.)

Answer (score -2):

Years late to the game, but for anyone stumbling upon this, there still does not seem to be a native, fluent way to safely navigate a Python dict.

Enter [RestResponse](https://github.com/MobiusWorksLLC/RestResponse):

"RestResponse aims to be a fluent python object for interfacing with RESTful JSON APIs"

This library includes a NoneProp object that allows for safely navigating (and building) JSON data structures.

```
>>> import RestResponse
>>> data = RestResponse.parse({})
>>> data.property.is_none
None
>>> bool(data.property.is_none)
False
>>> isinstance(data.property.is_none, RestResponse.NoneProp)
True
>>> data.property.is_none = None
>>> isinstance(data.property.is_none, RestResponse.NoneProp)
False
>>> print data.pretty_print()
{
    "property": {
        "is_none": null
    }
}
```